# Error #1069 in flash

Tags: actionscript-3

Error #1069: Property data not found on flash.display.SimpleButton and there is no default value. Can anyone give me a suggestion what will be the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a SimpleButton somewhere, and you try to access a property with the name `data` which doesn't exist. SimpleButton doesn't have a `data` property.